# How can i fix this import data

Tags: google-sheets

How can I fix this import data?

I imported data from matomo.com and I get data but with some errors in data like (�) and I can't use any other function.

How can I clean this data that I imported to use for my google sheet?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try removing `�`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A4; "�"; )
```

for the whole array:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(A:A; "�"; ))
```